# Angular use property binding in property binding

Tags: angular

I wanna use a property, in this case a string, to get an attribute of an object.

I thought of something like this:

**cIC** -> Object with attribute nameDe

**language** -> String with nameDe

```
<p *ngFor="let cIC of this.customerInformation">
  {{ cIC.{{ language }} }}
</p>
```

Comment: small suggestion - when rendering an gFor loop - you do NOT include the this. terminologiy - your loop should be 

<p *ngFor="let cIC of customerInformation">
    {{ cIC.language }}
</p>

or 

<p *ngFor="let cIC of customerInformation">
    {{ cIC[language] }}
</p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
<p *ngFor="let cIC of this.customerInformation">
  {{ cIC[language] }}
</p>
```

or

```
<p *ngFor="let cIC of this.customerInformation">
  {{ cIC?.language }}
</p>
```

Comment: A small suggestion - if using the null check - you should provide an alternative in case it is null (otherwise nothing at all will render in the interpolation ...   {{ cIC?.language || 'None listed'}} ...

Comment: Now when I change the array of the customerInformation the cIC[language] doesn't show anything. It's still there. When I just show cIC then it shows that the object is still there. Why could that be?

Comment: @MartinKarmela try logging it in the console and see if the property exists in and if it does, then verify if it is in nested object

Answer (score 0):

Use key accessor

```
<p *ngFor="let cIC of this.customerInformation">
  {{ cIC[language] }}
</p>
```